# Turtle crashes while playing music with playsound2

Tags: python, python-turtle, python-playsound

I have simple python turtle code which works fine, but when I add music, music plays, but turtle program crashes. What are the fixes for that? Here is my code:

```
import turtle
import playsound2

t = turtle.Turtle()

playsound2.playsound("song.mp3")

t.forward(50)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All python code below line 6 will not execute until music stops playing. You need two create two separate threads: one for your turtle code and one for music. You can do that this way:

```
import turtle
import playsound2
from threading import Thread

def play_music():
    playsound2.playsound("song.mp3")

def turtle_code():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.forward(50)

    turtle.mainloop()

thread1 = Thread(target=play_music)
thread2 = Thread(target=turtle_code)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```